# Mime types in Nestjs

Tags: nestjs

I just created a new Nestjs app and added an Angular project.

Im using:

```
 use(req: Request, res: Response, next: Function) {
        console.log("Hit the request");
        res.sendFile(resolve('../frontend/dist/frontend/index.html'));
      }
```

Sending the file works just fine. The browser receives the index.html
The error I'm getting is:
Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

I am aware that you have to include differenct Mime types for the server to allow the request. But where in the world in the NestJS documentation is that??

Regards,
Daniel

Comment: getting the same error, but haven't been able to resolve it yet. It looks like the  Nestjs doesn't support this kind of resource type?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you problem is that you are sending the index.html file as a response to all requests. It is likely that your index.html file will make a request to get a javascript file. Your server looks like it is responding again with index.html. So your browser is requesting a file with a javascript mime type but receiving one with "text/html".

Comment: Yes this is correct. I think I have found the documentation for serving SPA applications. I'll review. Thanks!